# Android App for making group video call(more than two participants) by utilizing Skype

Tags: android, skype

Greeting,

Can "Skype uri", "Skype Web SDK" or other options help to make my android app initiate (more than two participant in the video call)? I want to know all the options that Skype can provide me to make my developed app import the Skype functionality or to make my android app run the client Skype which will take care of handling the video call.

for your information, I used the Skype uri and it works fine with two participants. s**kype:skype.test.user.1;skype.test.user.2;skype.test.user.3?call&video=true** 
However, it did not initiate a group video call with more than two participants. Check this link for more information msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn745882.aspx. They mentioned that "Mobile Skype clients (iOS and Android) do not support initiating/hosting group video calls". Therefor, based on my understanding Skype uri is not going to help me.

Thanks for your help
Ziad

Comment: RTC is the way to go buddy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no, it is impossible to do what you ask.

As mentioned in [the link you provided](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn745882.aspx), Skype on iOS and Android does not support hosting or initiating a group video call. Additionally, even if you could somehow get around that, mobile clients can join a call with voice only (Mentioned in your link).

Skype Web SDK [does not allow video or audio on mobile devices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn705760(v=office.16).aspx):

> The core framework enables presence, contacts, note and chat services that can be utilized by a mobile app via JavaScript. Media capability such as audio, video and desktop sharing however, is currently enabled via the Skype for Business Web App plugin available for browsers such IE and Firefox. **This restricts all media modalities to desktops browsers only, as mobile browsers such as mobile Safari and the Windows Store browser do not allow 3rd party plugins.**

Answer (score 0):

based on my research and also as mention by NitrogenReaction on previous answer.

currently, Skype URI can not initiate a group video call with more than two participants (in Android).

for hangouts, currently, it doesn't provide API for Android developers.

therefore, I built my application by using ooVoo video chat SDK. The SDK allows me to import the video chat(12 participants) in my application. Chick this link for more information https://developers.oovoo.com/docs.

If you want to find other vendors that can provide you with a video chat SDK, go to this link https://bloggeek.me/missing-webrtc-paas-report/

thanks, 
z